# Traffic coming from campaign ads. shows as direct traffic in Google Analytics

Tags: php, google-analytics, web-analytics

When User coming from the **Google Adwords** or **Facebook ads**.It counts as a direct traffic instead of refferal traffic. I am using redirection on landing page of website.So, when user type www.abc.com it will redirect to the home page (www.abc.com/home.php).

My question is that how can i identify that how much traffic is coming from Referral and direct ?

Comment: You asked the same thing here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26204440/traffic-coming-from-campaign-adsi-e-google-or-facebook-shows-as-direct-traffi

Comment: @EikePierstorff That account will be deleted tomorrow. I want to save your answer for future use. Thats why I asked same question here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enable `autotagging` in your `adwords account` and make sure that your redirect does not strip out parameters (`gclid` must be present in the url),then link Analytics account and Adwords Account. 
Add `utm parameters` to your facebook links (support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033867?hl=en). This won't help with data already collected but will allow you to track campaigns in the future.

**You can create auto tagging url from here :**

[Google Analytics Url Builder](http://gaconfig.com/google-analytics-url-builder/)